# "You need to not only think short term but long term too"

Tags: sentence-structure

> You need to not only think short term but long term too.

Is this sentence wrong or right?

Answer (score 1):

It would be with the addition of a comma; the parenthetical portion is optional, just for illustration:

> You need to not only think short term, but *(to think)* long term too.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to not only think short term but long term too

What you want to express is a combination of two ideas:

> You need to think short term
>   You need to think long term too

To parallel these two ideas nicely, you need to have to common part "You need to think" before both of them. Also, it is conventional to use **but also** with **not only**:

> You need to think **not only** short term **but also** long term